# RMM direct replies to subdomain email adressess

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio, reply-mail-management

We got RMM working with dynamic sender profiles. We are using the following dynamic sender profile:

- From Name: %%AM_Name%% (Jon Snow)
- From Email: %%AM_Sub_Email%% (j.snow@**mc**.company.com)
- Reply Name: %%AM_Name%% (Jon Snow)
- Reply Email: %%AM_Email%% (j.snow@company.com)

Configuration:

- Domain: company.com
- Subdomain: mc.company.com
- SAP and SSL's in place?: Yes
- RMM Configured?: Yes

This works fine when customers reply directly on the email. The nice string is generated and the reply is forwarded to our accountmanagers.

However, we have some cases where our customers try to email our accountmanagers directly on the subdomain email (j.snow@**mc**.company.com). They get confused and sometimes think our accountmanagers got two email addresses.

I would have hoped these replies would be forwarded to the address that we configured in our RMM settings (Routing Address for Remaining Replies). This is not the case.

Did we do something wrong in our RMM configuration?

OR

Is it even possible to forward these replies to an address with a inbox?

Comment: Asked the same question via a case. Support agent says RMM doesn't support direct email sends to the SAP subdomain email addresses (e.g. j.snow@mc.company.com). 

Does anyone here has another solution for this use case?

Comment: Salesforce support gave the following answer: "The RMM features and direct forward features only apply when a subscriber hits 'reply'. If they reply and manually enter an email address there is no feature available for handling this.". Seems that it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you send an email directly to the sender From Address, then the email goes to a black hole. Nothing happens and you are not able to retrieve that mail.

Subscribers must hit the "reply" button so the correct reply-to email address is populated in the reply email. The reply-to email address is customised per subscriber per send, which allows the platform to identify the contact from their inbound reply.